# Does gcc support embedded assembler syntax?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

William Hohl's ARM Assembly Language book talks about Embedded assembler syntax. An example of it can be found on [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205j/Caciddae.html) on ARM reference manual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__asm void my_strcpy(const char *src, char *dst)
{
loop
      LDRB  r2, [r0], #1
      STRB  r2, [r1], #1
      CMP   r2, #0
      BNE   loop
      BX    lr
}
```

When I google 'gcc embedded assembler' syntax I only get the following [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=embedded%20assembly%20gcc). Does gcc only support what it calls “[extended assembly syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)?”

```
 asm [volatile] ( AssemblerTemplate
                  : OutputOperands
                  [ : InputOperands
                  [ : Clobbers ] ])
```

Comment: Yeah, gcc only supports the style you linked. It doesn't suppot that other style. Write assembler files directly if you want to write your assembler code like that.

Comment: Please don't link only, copy what you are referring to because the links might be down in the future

Comment: @FUZxxl, consider I want to write an FFT routine in assembly, and I get an input in C type array. How do I pass that array to my assembly routine in separate file?

Comment: @user1343318 You declare the function with the desired prototype in C and write its implementation in assembly. You need to make sure that your implementation matches the desired calling convention.

Comment: Yeah.. FFT.  Use a separate, dedicated assembler and link in.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** GCC does *not* support embedded assembly functions like the one shown in your example. You would have to use e.g. a KEIL compiler for that.

The two forms of inline assembly that are supported by GCC are the "simple" (which is just one of the variants of the `asm` keyword followed by curly braces) and the much more useful "extended" form which allows you to map variables for input and output to registers or classes of registers in a very flexible and efficient way. You can write almost register-agnostic assembly that works and fully uses the compiler's capacity for low-level optimizations (it obviously cannot do high-level optimizations, that would be asked a bit too much!).
Unluckily, the syntax is a bit... unintuitive at first.

In order to get the same effect as in your embedded assembly `my_strcpy` function, you would have to write an ordinary function that contains an extended assembly block, and map the function's arguments to inputs (and don't forget to clobber `memory`).

Note that GCC inline assembly has a few additional quirks which may come as a surprise. For one, it uses AT&T notation, and then you have to explicitly add `\n` to every line to prevent the assembler from complaining (or `\n\t` if you intend to check intermediate files and care about readable output).
The first quirk (AT&T notation) is actually a benefit since it is a lot more intuitive than Intel notation, you only have to know about it in the first place. On the other hand, the need to explicitly add escaped newlines is... bleh. Luckily, you don't really need to use assembly often (if ever).